# with just javascript can you combine file input upload and speechSynthesis -no jquery please

Tags: javascript, html

So here is a basic code idea of what I am trying to do. I would like to press a button select a text file and have it read it to me. Basically just reading short notes and stuff that were entered in txt. Still new playing with javascript. this seems easy enough but Google came back empty? can this even be done?

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<button onclick="speak(myFile)">speak dang it</button>
<script>
 function speak(text) {
 var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
 var voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
 msg.voice = voices[2];
 msg.voiceURI = 'native';
 msg.volume = 1;
 msg.rate = 1;
 msg.pitch = 1;
 msg.text = text;
 msg.lang = 'en-US';
 speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Parse the files value atrabute to speak and you may need to convert the file type to readable text

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have access to the file via `window.FileReader` or `window.Blob`.

Have a read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

## Update

Example:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" id="myFile">
<button id="speak">speak dang it</button>
<script>
    if( window.FileReader && window.speechSynthesis ) {
        const fileInput = document.getElementById("myFile");

        fileInput.addEventListener("change", event => {
            const Reader = new FileReader();
            Reader.readAsText( fileInput.files[ 0 ] );

            Reader.onload = event => {
                const contents = Reader.result;
                const utterThis = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance( contents );

                speechSynthesis.speak( utterThis );
            }

        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You should make sure you sanitise the input and check file type and all that but this is the smallest example I can think of...

Comment: care to upvote again @pablo so it doesn't look like this is somehow wrong?